# How do I obtain the current size of my heap from within my program?

Tags: c, linux, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation, heap-memory

I'm writing a C program running on Linux (with a less-than-10-yro kernel in case it matters).

From within that program, I want to determine what the overall size of my process' heap at some point.

I know I can do this in a round-about way by reading `/proc/mypidhere/maps` and parsing that - but I want to do it more directly and without messing withe files and strings.

Notes:

- I don't need the *limit* value, I need the current size of the heap.
- I realize `mmap()`'ed regions can also be part of the heap. I am interested both in answers which address the this fact, and in answers which ignore it.

Comment: *I know I can do this in a round-about way by reading /proc/mypidhere/maps and parsing that*  Not really - `glibc` on Linux manages heap memory with both `mmap()` and `brk()`, and there's no real way to distinguish the source of `mmap()`'d anonymous pages from just the address space map.

Comment: Usually it is not limited and as large as virtually address space. You can only try to see when malloc will fail.

Comment: Does this help? https://linux.die.net/man/2/getrlimit

Comment: @AndrewHenle: See edit.

Comment: @0___________: I didn't ask about the limit, I asked about the current size.

Comment: @Devolus: I want to obtain the current size, not some limit.

Answer (score 3):

On Linux with `glibc`, you can use [`malloc_info()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc_info.3.html) to get heap usage statisics:

> SYNOPSIS
>
> ```
>    #include <malloc.h>
>
>    int malloc_info(int options, FILE *stream);
> ```
>
> DESCRIPTION
>
> The `malloc_info()` function exports an XML string that describes
> the current state of the memory-allocation implementation in the
> caller.  The string is printed on the file stream stream.  The
> exported string includes information about all arenas (see
> malloc(3)).
>
> As currently implemented, options must be zero.

That produces an XML document that you have to parse.  But you might be able to use [`mallinfo()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mallinfo.3.html) to get heap usage statistics (but see [the **BUGS** section](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mallinfo.3.html#BUGS)):

> **SYNOPSIS**
>
> ```
>    #include <malloc.h>
>
>    struct mallinfo mallinfo(void);
> ```
>
> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> The `mallinfo()` function returns a copy of a structure containing
> information about memory allocations performed by malloc(3) and
> related functions.
>
> Note that not all allocations are visible to mallinfo(); see BUGS
> and consider using malloc_info(3) instead.
>
> The returned structure is defined as follows:
>
> ```
>        struct mallinfo {
>            int arena;     /* Non-mmapped space allocated (bytes) */
>            int ordblks;   /* Number of free chunks */
>            int smblks;    /* Number of free fastbin blocks */
>            int hblks;     /* Number of mmapped regions */
>            int hblkhd;    /* Space allocated in mmapped regions (bytes) */
>            int usmblks;   /* See below */
>            int fsmblks;   /* Space in freed fastbin blocks (bytes) */
>            int uordblks;  /* Total allocated space (bytes) */
>            int fordblks;  /* Total free space (bytes) */
>            int keepcost;  /* Top-most, releasable space (bytes) */
>        };
> ```

However,

> **BUGS**
>
> Information is returned for only the main memory allocation area.
> Allocations in other arenas are excluded.  See malloc_stats(3)
> and [malloc_info(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc_info.3.html) for alternatives that include information
> about other arenas.
>
> The fields of the mallinfo structure are typed as int.  However,
> because some internal bookkeeping values may be of type long, the
> reported values may wrap around zero and thus be inaccurate.

Comment: 1. What are "other arenas"? 2. Should I add up `mallinfo::arena` and `mallinfo::hblkhd`? Or  use `mallinfo::uordblks`? 3. If the value is in bytes, why do the field names mention blocks? 4. What if more than 2^31-1 bytes are allocated?

Comment: @einpoklum I don't have enough experience with either of these functions to know what the numbers actually mean - when I get into heap management it's been for debugging purposes and Valgrind or something similar is a better tool for that.  This link describes the internal `glibc` heap implementation much better than I can:  https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/MallocInternals